# Best way to export a git repo and include reflog

Tags: git, git-reflog

I want to save and share a git repo with everything in it, including the current `reflog` state. Is the best way to do this just to zip up the `.git` directory? Or could there be a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use `git bundle` for this purpose.

#### ***How to create git bundle?***

```
git bundle create mybundle --all
```

---

Or choose other flags as well instead of the `--all`

***`--branches[=<pattern>]`***

> Pretend as if all the refs in `refs/heads` are listed on the command line as `<commit>`.
> If `<pattern>` is given, limit branches to ones matching given shell glob.
> If pattern lacks `?`, `,` or `[`, `/` at the end is implied.

***`--tags[=<pattern>]`***

> Pretend as if all the refs in refs/tags are listed on the command line as `<commit>`.
> If `<pattern>` is given, limit tags to ones matching given shell glob.
> If pattern lacks `?`, `,` or `[, /` at the end is implied.